# Prevent SwiftUI redrawing all subviews

Tags: swift, swiftui, redraw

Here is a simple example of a more complex problem I'm having.

In this case, I have an array of `Object`s, and a struct that holds the state for them.

In the `ContentView`, I'm displaying a custom view, `MyToggle`, for each object, and passing the state via a `Binding`

```
struct Object: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    let name: String
}

struct ObjectStates {
    var states: [Object.ID: Bool] = [:]

    subscript(objectId: Object.ID) -> Bool {
        get { states[objectId, default: false] }
        set { states[objectId] = newValue }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {

    let objects = [Object(name: "Toggle 1"), Object(name: "Toggle 2"), Object(name: "Toggle 3"), Object(name: "Toggle 4"), Object(name: "Toggle 5")]
    @State var objectStates = ObjectStates()
    
    var body: some View {
        List(objects) { object in
            MyToggle(name: object.name, isOn: $objectStates[object.id])
        }
    }
}

struct MyToggle: View {
    let name: String
    @Binding var isOn: Bool
    
    var body: some View {
        let _ = print(name)
        let _ = Self._printChanges()
        
        Toggle(name, isOn: $isOn)
    }
}
```

Each time a `Toggle` is changed, `ObjectStates` is updated, and all the subviews are redrawn. The `Self._printChanges()` is used to demonstrate this.

**Is there a way to prevent all the subviews being redrawn when the state in the superview changes?**

Interestingly, if I add another `@State` on the superview…

```
struct ContentView: View {

    let objects = [Object(name: "Toggle 1"), Object(name: "Toggle 2"), Object(name: "Toggle 3"), Object(name: "Toggle 4"), Object(name: "Toggle 5")]
    @State var objectStates = ObjectStates()
    @State var isOn = false. // added this State
    
    var body: some View {
        List {
            Toggle("Main", isOn: $isOn) // change it here
            ForEach(objects) { object in
                MyToggle(name: object.name, isOn: $objectStates[object.id])
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The subviews are `not` redrawn when this state is updated.

Comment: There are quite a few things one can try... did you try to use viewmodel and not @State variable?

Comment: you know nothing is being "redrawn" ;-)

Answer (score 3):

First to the reason why this happens.

Both structs `ObjectStates` and `Object` are value types the same as the `states` dictionary. If you change a value type it gets destroyed and a new copy with the changed values is created. This new entity has a new id. The `@State` property wrapper detects changes by changes of the id of its wrapped value. That´s the reason we are using structs in SwiftUI. If you would use classes changes won´t reflect into the UI.

When an `@State` property is changed it sends its `objectWillChange` publisher. The SwiftUI View now tries to evaluate if it needs to change the presented view.
(Keep in mind the Views we are writing in SwiftUI are just a description of the view not the view itself.) To evaluate changes it calls the body var. Now when SubViews depend on any changed var it needs to evaluate these too. It can´t just guess if something changed or not. It has to run the `body` and compare it to the previous one.

That´s what you are seeing here. The subviews depend on `objectStates` so it has to call all `MyToggle` body vars to determine if they changed or not. It won´t call them in your second example because they do not depend on the changed `@State var isOn`.

**Conclusion:**

I don´t think there is something wrong with your approach. Calling the body var multiple times shouldn´t be of any concern. They should be lightweighted and easy to destroy / create anyway. List **should** only call the body var of the visible elements, so there should be no impact on performance if you have larger collections.

---

There is a work around for this. But it will have drawbacks as it uses a class to avoid the reevaluation of the subviews.

Change the struct to a class and implement ObservableObject

```
class ObjectStates: ObservableObject {
    var states: [Object.ID: Bool] = [:]
    
    subscript(objectId: Object.ID) -> Bool {
        get { states[objectId, default: false] }
        set { states[objectId] = newValue }
    }
}
```

Declare it `@StateObject` inside your View. This is needed to bind the lifecycle of the class to the view.

```
@StateObject var objectStates = ObjectStates()
```

Now you can use the `Toggle`s without recreating the `MyToggle` struct.

And of course the mandatory link to the video that´s more or less a must watch if working with SwiftUI -> [Demystify SwiftUI](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2021/10022/)